# How to get resource server text from client server in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have 3 servers running, UI(or client), Resource server and Authentication server. Everything thing works perfectly except getting the information from resource server to client. If I use postman or any other rest service program, I get the token from Authentication server and then use the token to get info from research server. Right now I go to my client server, if I am not authenticated I get redirected to Authorization server where I log in, it puts me back to client server, it should display a simple line like:

> lights are off

but I only get 404 null error what is supposed to mean it doesn't get the token with the request.

In my resource server is a simple line:

> {"lights":"lights are off"}

Any help is appreciated on how to get the info from resource server with the token attached to it.

My resource server code:

```
LightBoot.java 
@RestController public class LightsBoot {
    private static final String lights = "lights are %s";
    @RequestMapping(value = "/lights")
    public Lights greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "off") String name) {
        return new Lights(String.format(lights, name));
    } }
```

and my client code:

```
  @SpringBootApplication public class ClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClientApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext clientContext, OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details) {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(details, clientContext);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    } } 

@RestController public class NewController {


    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${endpoint.lights}")
    private String lights;


    @Autowired
    public NewController(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }


    public GetLights newLight() {
        return restTemplate.getForObject(lights, GetLights.class);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String lights() {

        return newLight() + "     <--- here should be value of lights";
    }

}
```

Client properties looks like:

```
auth-server: http://localhost:8081/authserver
resource-server: http://localhost:8082/resource
endpoint:
  lights: http://localhost:8082/resource/lights
server:
  port: 8080
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: user
      client-secret: user-secret
      access-token-uri: ${auth-server}/oauth/token
      user-authorization-uri: ${auth-server}/oauth/authorize
      scope: USER
      authorized-grant-types: authorization_code
    resource:
      token-info-uri: ${auth-server}/oauth/check_token
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
```

**EDIT1**
console outputs of my client app

```
Redirecting to 'http://localhost:8081/authserver/oauth/authorize?client_id=jan&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code&scope=USER&state=qJE3Rp'
Retrieving token from http://localhost:8081/authserver/oauth/token
2017-08-10 14:47:48.898 DEBUG 17560 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] g.c.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider : Encoding and sending form: {grant_type=[authorization_code], code=[0zeUdq], redirect_uri=[http://localhost:8080/login]}
2017-08-10 14:47:48.928 DEBUG 17560 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@327cec
2017-08-10 14:47:48.929 DEBUG 17560 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfAuthenticationStrategy@1dd8d6
2017-08-10 14:47:48.929 DEBUG 17560 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] uth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication@e5d78cca: Principal: user; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: remoteAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearertokenValue=<TOKEN>; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
2017-08-10 14:47:48.929 DEBUG 17560 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] RequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler : Redirecting to DefaultSavedRequest Url: http://localhost:8080/
2017-08-10 14:47:48.929 DEBUG 17560 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to 'http://localhost:8080/'
```

Comment: When you say "it puts me back to client server", what do you mean specifically? Does the authorization server return a redirect response? If so, where is that redirecting you to? It sounds like you're being sent to an incorrect URL at that point.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave I added an edit, to show what console prints out. To access my client i go to http://localhost:8080, it takes me to authorize server, i log in and then i go back to http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `@ResponseBody` annotation to your `lights()` method in the `NewController`, so it will look like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
@ResponseBody
public String lights() {
    return newLight() + "     <--- here should be value of lights";
}
```

What I suspect is happening (although this is mostly a guess, and will be very dependent upon your config) is that the value returned by the `lights()` method, which I think is the String `lights are off     <--- here should be value of lights`, is being interpreted by Spring as a view name, so it's looking for a file called something like `lights are off     <--- here should be value of lights.html` somewhere like `src/main/resources/templates`, which of course it's not finding.

The `@ResponseBody` annotation tells Spring to just return the value as the content of the response.

Comment: saddly no, in resourceApp console I get 
Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point and Written [error="unauthorized", error_description="Full authentication is required to access this resource"] so it seems it not actually getting the token with the request.

Comment: I think i should add that Client server is using Sso to run, if that makes any difference. The code i´I followed, used h2 database in resource server and then it worked.